# Aptana + Rails + Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, aptana

I want to know if its possible to use a remote ruby interpreter with Aptana (in a virtual machine, using vagrant) for Rails development. I've been using Rubymine so far, but the new pricing model of Jetbrains highly discouraged me to continue with them. Tks